# how to use min_ function in LinExpr() when writing an expression in Gurobi

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I would like to use the built-in min function provided by Gurobi, however, I receive an error and cannot use the variable within the function.

After installing the required libraries as shown below,

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import quicksum, min_
```

I write down my expression with pre-defined variables.

```
expr = gp.LinExpr(0)
for location in locations:
   for time in range(time_range):
        expr.add(min_(flow_variable[location, time], constant=0))
```

I used [this reference](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_min_.html) for the `_min` function.

```
  File "src\\gurobipy\\linexpr.pxi", line 212, in gurobipy.LinExpr.add
gurobipy.GurobiError: Unsupported type (<class 'gurobipy.GenExprMin'>) for LinExpr addition argument
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message already reads, you cannot have general expressions like the min function in a `LinExpr`.

I also don't see what you are trying to minimize, as the min function only receives a single variable `flow_variable[location,time]`.

Maybe you want to get the minimum of all variables `flow_variable[location,time]`:

```
min_flow = model.addVar()
model.addConstr(
    min_flow=min_(
        [flow_variable[l, t] for l in location for t in time_range], constant=0
    )
)
```

Comment: I can have a negative flow since flow variable is free. It will go into the objective function.